# Is there any Office.js API to get user input

Tags: office-js, office-js-helpers

In task pane of our [Office.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/word-add-ins-reference-overview) WORD add-in, we need to get a user input and display in the document. Is it even possible to get user input in an `Office.js` add-in. If so, is there any Office.js API for that?

Comment: hello, if you can add more details on your question will be really helpful. An add-in can show  an html page (task pane) where you can put controls (i.e textbox) and then you can use the JavaScript API to send that text to the document.  you can also show a dialog to the user (check dialog API) . I can tell you more details in the answer if you can clarify your question. thanks!

Comment: @JuanBalmori Got it. That's exactly what I was looking for (thank you). You may want to change your comment to an Answer w/ some helpful relevant links, and I will mark it as an answer.

Comment: please check our this article with details on how to do it.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins